# What exactly does has() return when the element is found

Tags: jquery

hey guys i am trying to build a small snippet to tell me if a given parent element has a child element , i am still just  debugging stuff , to understand how Jquery and JS work in general .heres what i have so far :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                    var str_dv = $('#la');
                    $('p , span').on('click' , function(e){


                        // console.log( str_dv,e.target , str_dv.has(e.target), !str_dv.has(e.target).length)
                        if (str_dv.has(e.target).length > 0) {
                            console.log('has the element');
                        }   

                    });
            });
```

i am just curious , but when i say `parent.has(child)` what will has() return if the child is found and what will it return if the child is not found ?

I serached SO for a similar question but could't find one , not even the Jquery doc's .

if i look at the Jquery source , i see :

```
"has": markFunction(function( selector ) {
            return function( elem ) {
                return Sizzle( selector, elem ).length > 0;
            };
        }),
```

which does't exactly make alot of sense to me .

so once again coming back to my question , what does has() return ? (when the element passed is found and also when not found) ?

Comment: Why not just read the docs -> *"the .has() method constructs a new jQuery object from a subset of the matching elements"*

Comment: @adeneo but nothing explicity says what has() will return ?, so does it return the newly constructed object or does has() just return true or false ?

Comment: It returns the elements that match, i.e. that has the elements targeted

Comment: This should be trivial to test -> **http://jsfiddle.net/e0rmmpmr/**

Comment: @adeneo , so if i say $('div').has('p') , and the div has a child <p> , i will get p after the check if complete is it ? and what if p is not a child of div , in that case will i get false ?

Comment: No, you'd get the `div`, as it has a `p`, if doesn't have a `p` you'll get a jQuery object with no elements and a length of zero

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh i seee and thats Why i guess we have the following test `$('div').has('p').length > 0` ?

Comment: Yes, it checks if any divs exist that has a `p` child

Comment: @adeneo , great than thats my answer !! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we use the has() function as follows :

my question was actually not how the has() funtion works , but when does the following test return true or false :

`$('div').has('p').length > 0`

`$('div').has('p')` , and p is indeed a child of $('div') , Jquery returns an object with a property of length:1 and so the below test will be true .

`$('div').has('p').length > 0`

but when p is not a child of $('div') , Jquery will return an object with a property of length:0 and so `$('div').has('p').length > 0` will return false.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkcLLjds/)

Thanks adeneo.

Comment: @RahulDesai huh . where ? i'll give u +1 for being elaborate , but ur answer does't clarify when , why and how does `$('div').has('p').length > 0` work .

Comment: I had it in the code, but yeah I will make sure to elaborate on it more next time when I am in such situation.

Answer (score 1):

*what does has() return ?*

As per Docs,

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

thus has filters the element in matched set by elements that have the child elements whose selector is passed in has.

For example the selector is:

```
$("li").has("ul");
```

This will select only that li elements, which has ul element inside them.

**[Demo For has selector](http://jsfiddle.net/j2yt7w3j/)**

Answer (score 1):

`.has()` will return an object with the matched elements. Its so, so that it can be used for chaining.

As per [the official jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/has/), what `.has()` does is:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

Check out this demo:

```js
console.dir($('div').has('p')); // check what it returns in the console

console.dir($('div').has('span')); // check what it returns in the console

if($('div').has('p').length){  // used as a condition
  alert('This "div" has a "p".');
}

if($('div').has('span').length){  // used as a condition
  alert('This "div" has a "span".');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Checkout the official docs here: http://api.jquery.com/has/